# What kinds of quotes to use with mysqli_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication, mysqli

I created the following script in procedural mysqli because I am just starting from the old mysql. I am not sure about the kinds of quotes around the query to prevent injections. Some users post examples with `'` others with `"`, so now I'm confused. Can I get injected or attacked with the following code and what are the correct kinds of quotes?

```
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['form_user']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$_POST['form_password']);

$members = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `member` = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($database,$members);
```

I am just a beginner so object oriented or PDO or prepared statements are difficult for me at this moment so I just need to improve this script and make it safer but with so many examples and symbols around query vars I am confused about what is and is not safe.

Comment: To improve that script and make it safer you should use prepared statements - they aren't that hard to understand and if you wrote the above it won't take long to figure out. Your first step should be to format your code properly - the above is very hard to read.

Comment: Is this your code or did you get it from somewhere else? If you could highlight what areas you are specifically concerned about, that would help in answering your question.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string`. or just go straight to parameter binding.

Comment: If prepared statements are too hard for you, use https://github.com/resonantcore/lib/blob/develop/src/DB.php (wiki: https://github.com/resonantcore/lib/wiki/DB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_real_escape_string` defers to the underlying C mysql library's [`mysql_real_escape_string` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) (or equivalent), which encodes the characters:

> `\`, `'`, `"`, `NUL` (ASCII 0), `\n`, `\r`, and Control+Z

So, both `'` and `"` are being escaped. That means you can use either for delimiting your string in your query, MySQL [allows both double and single quoted strings](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-literals.html) equally.

I know you know this, but you really really should be getting on the [prepared-statement bandwagon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1) now instead of escaping.

Comment: The question is if I use procedural in query what is the safest way about symbuls used like ' " and ` what to use what is unsafe what is better. I forgot the `

Comment: \` is for delimiting column and table names and cannot be used in conjunction with real_escape_string at all.

Comment: That is what I am talking about, if this symbol cannot be used then the correct way when using real_scape_string should be $members = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE member = '$username'"; without the ` symbol ? Is this because of safety ?

Comment: No. ` is used if you need to delimit column names. It's fine for using on **column names**. It's not always necessary, but sometimes you need it, for example if your column name contains a special character and must be delimited. It doesn't really have anything to do with real_escape_string or security, since you're not putting any user input into column names, ***right.....!?***

Comment: so this is absolutly correct? 
   //  $members = "SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `member` = '$username'"; sorry the ` around accounts and member is not shown